# Tensorflow - shape error when reading data from file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a single layer perceptron (basing my code on [this](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py)) on the following data file in tensor flow:

```
1,1,0.05,-1.05
1,1,0.1,-1.1
....
```

where the last column is the label (function of 3 parameters) and the first three columns are the function argument. The code that reads the data and trains the model (I simplify it for readability):

```
import tensorflow as tf

... # some basics to read the data
example, label = read_file_format(filename_queue)
... # model construction and parameter setting

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: example, y: label})
    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

but when I run it, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nn.py", line 85, in <module>
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: example, y: label})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 710, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 887, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (3,) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 3)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph expects X to be a tensor of shape (?, 3). Your example data is of the shape (3,) i.e. a 1 dimensional vector of length 3. Either reshape example to (1, 3), or pass a batch of examples in one shot (e.g. 10, giving a shape of (10, 3))

Comment: is there a tensorflowy way of creating a batch? I tried example.reshape(1,3) but it made it worse it seems: "ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
"

Comment: No, that made it better! Now it's complaining about Placeholder_1, which is Y.  So reshape that to (-1, 1) and you should be good.

Comment: And don't worry, this is the tensorflowy way to create the batch. TF graphs start at the placeholders, so munge your data using natural methods as much as you need to create the batch.